# add value from different tables and insert total value into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, ssms, sql-server-2014

I have several tables (say 5 tables) and I want to sum a specific entry from each of the 5 tables and put that sum in one table.
Example:

Table_One

```
product_one_id    name    price
1                 item1   50.25
2                 item2   100.25
```

Table_Two

```
product_two_id    name    price
    1             item3   25.25
    2             item4   70.25
```

Table_Total

```
product_total_id    name    price_total
    1             total1   120.50    //get total from item1 + item4
    2             total2   125.50   //get total from item2 + item3
```

this my code: is not a correct syntax but to illustrate what I'm trying to do

```
INSERT INTO Table_Total(product_total_id, name, price_total)
VALUES (1, 'total1', ((select price from Table_One where product_one_id = 1) + (select price from Table_Two where product_two_id = 4));
```

Comment: What relates `product_one_id = 1` to `product_two_id = 2` to get the `price_total`?

Comment: @sgeddes's point is an important one.  What you want to do is simple if you can define the relationship between products 1 and 2.

Comment: I'm building a computer store database. Product_one_id are the model number of the computer part and price_total is the total. So a table has only cpu parts and their price and another has gpu parts and their price. One table that has the total price of cpu and gpu

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not completely sure why you need to do this, this should work using a `cross join` which essentially produces a `cartesian product`:

```
insert into table_total
select 1, 'total1', t1.price + t2.price
from table_one t1 cross join table_two t2
where t1.table_one_id = 1 
  and t2.table_two_id = 2;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2bf9/1)